# How to use a swing Timer with JPanel

Tags: java, swing, timer, jframe, jcomponent

I'm fairly sure I understand how a swing timer works, I just cannot figure out how to apply it in my code. The way I apply it in my code doesn't allow it to draw because Graphics g is outside of its scope.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JayFrame extends JFrame
{
  public JayFrame()
  {
    super("My Frame");
    setContentPane(new DrawPane());
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(1200, 675);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
  }

  class DrawPane extends JPanel
  {
    Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new MyTimer());

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
      //Paint stuff
      super.paintComponent(g);

      timer.start();

      for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i += 110)
      {
        g.fillRect(i, 10, 100, 100);

        try{Thread.sleep(100);}
        catch(InterruptedException ie){}
      }

      timer.stop();
    }
  }

  class MyTimer implements ActionListener
  {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
      //Loop stuff
      repaint();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    new JayFrame();
  }
}
```

EDIT: I have updated the code to show what I think should work, but does not. So I probably do have a flawed understanding of swing timers.

Comment: What does the "Loop stuff" do?  What does the "draw stuff" do?  When do you start the `Timer`?  This `Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new MyTimer());` looks strange, given the fact that you've started it from within your `MyTimer` class

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: `doesn't allow it to draw because Graphics g is outside of its scope.` in the ActionListener of your Timer you would invoke `repaint()` on the panel where you do your custom painting. In the constructor of your DrawPanel class you can create and start the Timer. There is no need for a separate MyTimer class.

Comment: I have updated the original post and added the suggestions from your comments.

I do not completely understand the third however, if I do not need the MyTimer class, of which I am completely fine with removing, where would I declare the ActionListener?

Comment: Don't call `timer.start();` and/or `timer.stop()` in the `paintComponent` method, this makes no sense what so ever, painting may occur for any number of reasons, my of which you have no control over.

Comment: Where would I go about putting them then?

Comment: Think about this way.  Each time `paintComponent` is called, you're going to iterate through you loop (roughly) 9 times, on each iteration, you're going to wait 1 second, so the loop is going to take 9 seconds to complete.  In that time, nothing will be rendered to the screen, nor will your app respond to any events from the user.  Instead, the `Timer` should be acting as the loop.  Each time the timer is triggered, you update the state (add `110` to some variable) and call `repaint`, you allow the `Timer` to continue running until the variable is `>= 1000` at which time you stop the timer.

Answer (score 3):

- Don't call `timer.start();` and/or `timer.stop()` in the `paintComponent` method, this makes no sense what so ever, painting may occur for any number of reasons, my of which you have no control over.
- Don't call `Thread.sleep` in your `paintComponent`, that's the point of have the `Timer`. You're just preventing Swing from updating the screen or process any new events

`Timer` acts as a psudo loop, on each iteration of the `Timer`, you update some state, check some exit condition and make your decisions about what should happen.

`paintComponent` simply paints the current state.

For example:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class JayFrame extends JFrame {

    public JayFrame() {
        super("My Frame");
        setContentPane(new DrawPane());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(1200, 675);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    class DrawPane extends JPanel {

        private int x = 0;

        public DrawPane() {
            Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    x += 110;
                    if (x >= 1000) {
                        x = 1000;
                        ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            //Paint stuff
            super.paintComponent(g);

            g.fillRect(x, 10, 100, 100);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                new JayFrame();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, so far, the best way I have found for myself to learn code is by example. I have been looking for an example for this for almost a year now. There are some parts I don't understand, but I'll read the docs and mess around with this until I do.

Comment: It can take a while for it to click (did for me), but the simplest way to think about it, is to see it as a kind of loop