# Move an oval to follow the cursor java

Tags: java

I would like some advice:

I am learning how to use swing and I have an assigment which proposes to make an application where user can choose from one combo box the JPanel's background's color (implemented as a custom Beam). Also we have other combo box to choose a shape's color.
The user needs to move the cursor and watch five ovals following it. So then I have done all the interface and I learnt how to use the timer to repaint the canvas every 100 ms.

INTERFACE:

[image: White and blue interface]

So how can I be able to store oval's lasts five positions? My code:

Base FRAME:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;


public class Frame extends javax.swing.JFrame {



    public Frame() {
        initComponents();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        chooseBackground = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        chooseShape = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        canvas1 = new lienzo();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        chooseBackground.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "WHITE", "BLACK", "PINK" }));
        chooseBackground.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                chooseBackgroundActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        chooseShape.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "BLUE", "YELLOW", "ORANGE" }));
        chooseShape.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                chooseShapeActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setText("Seleccione el color:");

        jLabel2.setText("Fondo:");

        jLabel3.setText("Figura:");

        canvas1.addMouseMotionListener(new java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter() {
            public void mouseMoved(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                canvas1MouseMoved(evt);
            }
        });
        canvas1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                canvas1MouseEntered(evt);
            }
            public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                canvas1MouseExited(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout canvas1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(canvas1);
        canvas1.setLayout(canvas1Layout);
        canvas1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            canvas1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        canvas1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            canvas1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 184, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(31, 31, 31)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(canvas1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addComponent(chooseBackground, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 59, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addComponent(chooseShape, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                        .addGap(97, 97, 97))))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(13, 13, 13)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(chooseBackground, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(chooseShape, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(canvas1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(33, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void chooseBackgroundActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        String selection =  chooseBackground.getSelectedItem().toString();

        Color color;
        try{
        Field field = Class.forName("java.awt.Color").getField(selection);
        color = (Color)field.get(null);
        }catch(Exception e){
            color = null;
        }

        canvas1.setBackground(color);

    }                                                

    private void chooseShapeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        String selection =  chooseShape.getSelectedItem().toString();

        Color color;
        try{
        Field field = Class.forName("java.awt.Color").getField(selection);
        color = (Color)field.get(null);

        }catch(Exception e){
            color = null;
        }

        canvas1.setForeground(color);




    }                                           

    private void canvas1MouseMoved(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                   
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        canvas1.setX(evt.getX());
        canvas1.setY(evt.getY());        
    }                                  

    private void canvas1MouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        canvas1.userHasMouseEntered=true;
    }                                    

    private void canvas1MouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        canvas1.userHasMouseEntered=false;
    }                                   



    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Frame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Frame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Frame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Frame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Frame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }







    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private lienzo canvas1;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> chooseBackground;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> chooseShape;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    // End of variables declaration                   


}
```

CANVAS:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author YonePC
 */
public class lienzo extends JPanel {
    public boolean userHasMouseEntered;

    private int countSavedPos = 0;

    private int[] posX = new int[5];
    private int[] posY = new int[5];

    private int x;
    private int y;

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public lienzo() {
            Timer timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();

        this.setBackground(Color.white);
        this.setForeground(Color.blue);

    }


    @Override
    public  void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if(userHasMouseEntered)
        g.fillOval(x, y, 30, 30);



        posX[countSavedPos] = x;
        posY[countSavedPos] = y;
        countSavedPos++;
        if(countSavedPos>4) countSavedPos=0;

        for (int i = 0; i < countSavedPos; i++) {
            g.fillOval(posX[countSavedPos], posY[countSavedPos], 30, 30);


        }

        //repaint();
    }


}
```

In addition, I do not understand why the current oval which draws correctly under the cursor, is painted well but the second one which follows it blinks. Plus why do I have two ovals, am I not keeping the 5 last positions and repainting them?

Thank you for your time sincerely.

I have also seen:
[How to use a swing Timer with JPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32753169/how-to-use-a-swing-timer-with-jpanel)
[Converting a String to Color in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854043/converting-a-string-to-color-in-java)
[Move an Oval in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20792947/move-an-oval-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I have had help from classmates and I want to reply my own question:

To store mouse's last 5 positions we used into the canvas:

```
    private final ArrayList<Position> trail = new ArrayList<>();




public void addNewPosition(Position position){
       trail.add(0, position);       
}

public void removeLastPosition(){
    if (trail.size()> 5) trail.remove(5);
}
```

To update last 5 positions we put into the JFrame:

```
    private void canvas1MouseMoved(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                   
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    canvas1.addNewPosition(new Position(evt.getX(),evt.getY()));
    canvas1.removeLastPosition();
    repaint();

    /*
    canvas1.setX(evt.getX());
    canvas1.setY(evt.getY());*/        
}
```

To paint ovals and make them look separated, into the canvas:

```
   @Override
public  void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);

    if(userHasMouseEntered){

            for (int i = 0; i < trail.size(); i++) {
                g.fillOval(trail.get(i).getX(), trail.get(i).getY(), 30, 30);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(25);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(lienzo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }


    }   
    repaint();
}
```

Thank you.